# Git rebase without copying commits

Tags: git, github

I have a branch on a git repository. Since the branch was made there have been 50 commits to master. I have 2 commits on my branch and a open PR on GitHub. I now want to update my branch so that I can work with files that have newly changed in master.

If run `git rebase origin/master` it copies the 50 commits on master into my branch. It clobbers the GH PR as now says I want to merge 52 commits and a bunch of line changes, when I only want to merge the 2 commits.

What I want to do is modify the parent of the commit at the start of the branch to point to the current master head. Is this possible? Current thinking is to just close the PR and restart all the changes on a new branch. This doesn't feel like a very good method though.

Comment: You meant `git rebase origin/master`, not `master/origin`, right?

Comment: Note that `git rebase` is nearly always about copying commits. It's a method of doing `git cherry-pick` repeatedly, and each cherry-pick is a copy.

Comment: @Thomas yes, whoops. Have edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to force the last 2 commits on top of another branch:

```
git rebase --onto origin/master HEAD~2 my-branch
```

Then you will have to force-push into the remote branch of the PR.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is there a more generic command to this for N commits. Could I replace the 2 with the branch name?

Comment: You can use any reference that makes sense. Whatver you provide in place of `HEAD~2`  is what git **won't** move when doing the rebase. For example, say you have 2 branches, one after the other (branch1, branch2 started from branch12). Now you want to put branch2 on top of master, leaving branch1 behind (for whatever reason): `git rebase --onto master branch1 branch2`. I use this technique **a lot** when putting one branch on top of another branch that is being developed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use git squash to merge last few commits into a single commit.

```
git merge --squash bugfix
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what to do

1. create a new branch from origin/master `git checkout newbranch origin/master`
2. `git rebase --onto your-branch HEAD~2 newbranch`

also you can do this step by doing `cherry-pick`ing commits from your branch one by one